# How to make a launch file?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now let's create a launch file called turtlemimic.launch and paste the following:
I pull up gedit and copy/paste    1 
2
3   
4     
5   
6
7   
8     
9   
10
11   
12     
13     
14   
15
16 
into gedit with sudo and save it at /home/pc/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/launch
I $ cd ~/catkin_ws/   source devel/setup.bash
then I try to run roslaunch beginner_tutorials turtlemimic.launch
but i get the error

pc@pc:~$ cd ~/catkin_ws/
pc@pc:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
pc@pc:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch beginner_tutorials turtlemimic.launch
... logging to /home/pc/.ros/log/93f61492-23a7-11e4-bf9f-9439e5ec40e7/roslaunch-pc-3090.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: syntax error: line 1, column 3I

I don't know what im doing wrong, the file will only save as plain text and not XML, the tutorial does not say how to save files in XML

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190214/how-to-make-a-launch-file?/) by [HelpwithUbuntu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19984/helpwithubuntu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-08-14**:
Please use the code block formatting tool. It's the button with the 101010 in it. I always have to edit your questions to avoid eye cancer.

**Comment by [HelpwithUbuntu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19984/helpwithubuntu/) on 2014-08-14**:
Thanks for formatting my question, it looks ok when I put it in the question box but changes when it's posted. I have searched and I can't find out what a CODE BLOCK tool is. What is the button with 101010 and if all of this is important why is it not in the tutorial, it says beginner level. I am not playing dumb I really don't know what this stuff is.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-08-14**:
Do you really want to do robotics? The ROS tutorials are very easy and compared to real robotics a child's play.

**Comment by [HelpwithUbuntu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19984/helpwithubuntu/) on 2014-08-14**:
YES, I will get the hang of it just like anything else hard in life the more you do it the better you get. How was I suppose to know that I don't include the line numbers, the tutorial said copy and paste, I find it funny you asked about spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't copy-paste the line numbers from the tutorial page.

You always can disable the line numbers in ROS wiki code examples.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HelpwithUbuntu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19984/helpwithubuntu/) on 2014-08-14**:
Thank you so much, it works now. I don't understand why the tutorial does not tell me that.